# CakePHP hasMany relationship requiring plural classname

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm working on a cargo shipping application using CakePHP and I've found a workaround to my problem, but I still don't understand what the problem is.

This is my country model

```
class Country extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = 1;
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Port' => array(
            'className' => 'Ports'
        )
    );
}
```

This code works. But the following does not.

```
//Broken example #1
class Country extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = 1;
    public $hasMany = 'Port';
}
```

And neither does this.

```
//Broken example #2
class Country extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = 1;
    public $hasMany = 'Ports';
}
```

my database table is `ports`. My Model is `Port` and my controller is `PortsController`.

The cake documentation would have me believe that I should be using the singular name for the `hasMany` relationship. And using the singular name works for `belongsTo` relationships elsewhere in my program.

It's difficult to get debugging info because all the requests are ajax, but From what I'm able to see, the queries aren't any different.

Using the working code, my queries are:

```
SELECT `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`name` FROM `db`.`countries` AS `Country` WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT `Port`.`id`, `Port`.`country_id`, `Port`.`name` FROM `db`.`ports` AS `Port` WHERE `Port`.`country_id` IN (1, 3, 2)
```

Using broken example #1, the queries I get are:

```
SELECT `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`name` FROM `db`.`countries` AS `Country` WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT `Port`.`id`, `Port`.`country_id`, `Port`.`name` FROM `db`.`ports` AS `Port` WHERE `Port`.`country_id` IN (1, 3, 2)
```

So Why is this model acting so strange?

**Edit: Adding Port model**

```
class Port extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Country', 'Customer');    
}
```

Comment: Both sets of queries you have posted are identical.

Comment: I know. That's why I don't understand why One method works and the other doesn't.

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your **Broken example #1**? (In other words why do you think it is not working. It is generating the exact same SQL as the _working_ example.)

Comment: how about showing us your `Port` model ?

Comment: I am really surprised using `'className' => 'Ports'` works. Are you sure your model filename and class name are as per convention?

Comment: I've added my `Port` model code.
My filenames and class names are certainly following convention. 
All other relations are working as expected. Only the hasMany is showing this behaviour. An not only with `ports`. I've added a `hasMany Customer` relation `Country` and the same workaround was required.

Comment: Are you using any CakePHP plugins?

Comment: I am using DebugKit.